# Do we have incentive to burninate the [incentive] tag?

Tags: discussion, meta, burninate-request

The [incentive](/questions/tagged/incentive) tag has 18 questions ATM which aren't much. I can't see any benefit having such a tag, being meta and without any real value.

Should we burninate it?

If I'll see no compelling reason not to do that, I'll start in couple of days to remove it from questions. (Others are welcome too, but please wait to allow people to voice their objections.)

Comment: I am scanning through the questions because I wanted to write a replace-with-these-tags-answer and I am not sure it needs to be destroyed. What about [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185857/is-there-an-incentive-to-vote-to-close) question for example? Do you have an idea how to tag it? [tag:reputation] would include a bias towards possible ideas.

Comment: @MEE actually on first glance it looked like the tag can be safely removed without putting other tag instead. Will take deeper look, thanks. As for your example, don't think any extra tag is needed.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is true in all cases. [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90620/reward-finding-duplicate-questions-10-2-5) should for example be tagged with [reputation] instead.

Comment: P.S. There is also [tag:motivation] with 23 questions and also no tag wiki

Comment: @MEE  correct in both cases, yeah.

Comment: I would propose to retag the few questions that are possible (->reputation, badges, bounties, thanks) and then merge [incentive] and [motivation]. The tag also doesn't seem to fail Shog's critera for burnination.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer by Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/364003), a tag must exhibit a negative answer to all four of these questions in order to be considered for burnination:

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?
> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

I am not quite sure whether the tag fails each of these tests (especially regarding question two as questions about incentives from/in the Stack Exchange system are on-topic).

Also I discovered the tag [motivation](/questions/tagged/motivation) with 23 questions that seems strongly related/equivalent to [incentive](/questions/tagged/incentive).

**Therefore I vote against burnination. Instead I propose this tag replacement/merge procedure:**

1. Retag [incentive](/questions/tagged/incentive) appropriately to better tags:

   - [reputation](/questions/tagged/reputation) for questions about *reputation incentives for positive behavior*
   - [badges](/questions/tagged/badges) for questions about *badges as incentives for positive behavior*
   - [bounties](/questions/tagged/bounties) and [thanks](/questions/tagged/thanks) for questions about how to say thanks (to an answer, ...)
   - *or no tag if [incentive] adds no value to the question]
2. Synonymize/Merge [incentive](/questions/tagged/incentive) and [motivation](/questions/tagged/motivation)
3. Write a tag wiki for [motivation](/questions/tagged/motivation)

Comment: @rene I didn’t create this tag ;) But I agree that it is of not much use for anything not already discussed in the blog, etc. I only included it because it seemed to fit some of the questions in the incentive tag.